# Moodle Datatable

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, moodle

I am trying to create a datatable in Moodle. However, I have problem fetching data from the database and putting the data into the datatable. Can someone help me?
Here is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../../config.php';
global $USER, $DB,$CFG;

$PAGE->set_url('/local/glossary/index.php');
$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->requires->jquery();
//$PAGE->requires->js('/local/glossary/assets/glossary.js');
require_login();

$strpagetitle=get_string('glossary','local_glossary');
$strpageheading=get_string('glossary','local_glossary');
$PAGE->set_title($strpagetitle);
$PAGE->set_heading($strpageheading);

$sql = "SELECT id, term, definition FROM mdl_local_glossary";
$result = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
$result = new stdClass();

echo $OUTPUT->header();
echo $OUTPUT->render_from_template('local_glossary/searchbar',[]);
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of immediate issues with what you have written.

Firstly, you've hardcoded the 'mdl_' prefix, so this code will fail on any sites that use a different prefix (including any automated testing sites).

```
$sql = "SELECT id, term, definition FROM {local_glossary}";
```

Will fix it, or even better:

```
$result = $DB->get_records('local_glossary', [], 'id, term, definition');
```

The second problem, is that you retrieve the results (into an array called $result), then immediately overwrite these results with: $result = new stdClass();

If you want to pass the data into a template, then try something like:

```
echo $OUTPUT->render_from_template('local_glossary/searchbar', ['results' => $result]);
```

(after removing the unwanted $result = new stdClass(); line)